# Sql Query with 1 Join and 2 Where Clauses not returning all records

Tags: mysql, sql

So guys, trying to write a query to get the count of statuses where project_id = ? and statuses in 'New' from a couple of tables so let me break it down.

I have these three tables

Case_Status

```
id case_status   
1  New  
2  Failed
3. Accepted
```

Referral

```
id case_status_id project_id application_id 
1      1         1             20 
2      2         1             21
```

Project

```
id name 
1   project1 
2   project2
```

So this is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(referrals.id) AS count_all, case_statuses.case_status AS counted 
    FROM "case_statuses" LEFT OUTER JOIN "referrals" ON "referrals"."case_status_id" = "case_statuses"."id" 
    WHERE "case_statuses"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (case_statuses.case_status IN ('New') AND referrals.project_id = 1) 
    GROUP BY case_statuses.case_status;
```

This is my result

```
count_all  counted
1            New
1            Failed
```

But I am expecting this result instead

```
count_all  counted
    1            New
    1            Failed
    0            Accepted
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my query that isnt showing count for all the case_statuses?

Thanks

Comment: You are really getting "NEW" in the results? case_statuses.case_status NOT IN ('New') in the where statement should mean you are not getting it because you specifically exclude that status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions on the second table (in a `left join`) should be in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(r.id) AS count_all, cs.case_status AS counted 
FROM case_statuses cs LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     referrals r
     ON r.case_status_id = cs.id AND r.project_id = 1
WHERE cs.deleted_at IS NULL AND cs.case_status NOT IN ('New') 
GROUP BY cs.case_status;
```

Otherwise, the `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

change your query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(referrals.id) AS count_all, case_statuses.case_status AS counted 
    FROM "case_statuses" LEFT JOIN "referrals" ON "referrals"."case_status_id" = "case_statuses"."id"  AND referrals.project_id = 1
    WHERE "case_statuses"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND case_statuses.case_status NOT IN ('New')  
    GROUP BY case_statuses.case_status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data and the expected result you just need to loose the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(referrals.id) AS count_all, case_statuses.case_status AS counted 
FROM case_statuses
      LEFT OUTER JOIN referrals ON referrals.case_status_id = case_statuses.id 
GROUP BY case_statuses.case_status;
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ae74/6) for details.

Comment: what about referrals.project_id = 1, and "case_statuses"."deleted_at" IS NULL?  I would think at least the project_id should be part of the ON condition and who knows about the deleted_at column because it isn't present in his sample data.....

Comment: If further filtering on the right table in a `LEFT JOIN` is needed then it must be in the `ON` clause. See Gordon's answer.

Comment: I am aware of all of that, I was just trying to help yourself and Kingsley who asked the question understand that a few of his original criteria where not represented in your answer so that you could potentially expand the good direction you were moving to simplify and rectify the problem of having criteria from the right table in the Where clause.  Have a nice day